# Regular expression of `\f`

Tags: regex, ocaml

Under [Re](https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/re/),
I realized that

```
Str.global_replace (Str.regexp "[ \f\r\t\n]+") "" "if"
```

returns `"i"`, and

```
Str.global_replace (Str.regexp "[ \f\r\t\n]+") "" "igf"
```

returns `"ig"`.

Am I writing the correct regular expression? or is there anything wrong with global_replace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no escape sequence `\f` in OCaml:

```
# "\f";;
Warning 14: illegal backslash escape in string.
- : string = "\\f"
```

The others are legitimate. So you might have better luck with this:

```
Str.regexp "[ \012\r\t\n]+"
```